# iOS 10 push notification localization

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

Has anyone having problem with `Localization` push Notifications on `iOS10`?
In my loc-args arguments in `PushNotification` are sent as strings and integers and my mapping doesn't work. This is the string format in `Localizable.string`:

```
%1$@ - %2$@ %3$@:%4$@
```

First two arguments are strings and they are shown in `NotificationCenter`. The third and fourth are ints and they are not shown. 
On `iOS9`, if I use:

```
%1$@ - %2$@ %3$@:%4$@
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Finally, I have resolved by changing all args to string.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my question, it was resolved in next version of iOS 10, it was Apple bug and they fix it quickly after I filed radar.